# FTP or FTP-like solution which prevents users overwriting each other in files?

Tags: ftp

What i'm trying to do, is to prevent users to edit same file at the same time.

In example like it is on the windows shared folder, User 1 opens a spreadsheet and starts editing it, User 2 tries to open the same spreadsheet, but the warning message will popup and it can be opened as read only.

VPN and Shared folders are not in option.

So is there any kind of FTP or FTP-like solution or methodology for windows which can fill in my requirements?

Naming specific software is not necessary but advice on how to achieve this in general would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you describe is called a file lock and can be implemented in several ways, none of them specifically built in into FTP.

If you must use the FTP protocol then locking can be achieved by temporarily moving the file or changing its permissions until the locking user completed the transaction.

There are alternative file sharing protocols that that do offer built-in locking. For example, if you'll use SVN instead of FTP, the modifying user will have to check out a file in order to modify it and then once finished check it back in. There are plenty of SVN implementations for Windows.

If you want to use IIS then you can publish the files via WebDAV, the IIS WebDAV implementation supports locking as of WebDAV 7.0, see [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/webdav/authoring/locks) how to configure it.

Comment: ... SVN can have 2 people work on the same file though at the same time... And depending on the file type, may not be mergable

Comment: @Dave, not if you require checkout (of course it is always possible for someone to edit a _local_ copy but the question is about the central repository)

Comment: You could look for an event-driven FTP client or at least one which supports running some commands on server-side files before or after download/upload. Then, you'd use that to run a command like `chmod` to change the permissions of the file you're editing, and change them back to normal once you're finished with the file. The permissions could still allow (e.g.) Apache to read the files to avoid website interruption. [Serv-U](http://www.serv-u.com/server-events) and [WS_FTP](https://www.ipswitch.com/secure-information-and-file-transfer/wsftp-client) apparently offer event-driven commands.